# Fatal error: Call to a member function Select() on a non-object in

Tags: php, mysql, ооп, mysqli

Вот код, в строке 21 класса `M_Page ($result = $mMysql->Select('SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY date DESC');)` обращаюсь к методу объекта, который создала в конструкторе класса `M_Page`.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function Select() on a non-object in 
>   M_Page.php on line 21

Почему возникает ошибка?

```
include_once('M_MySQL.php');

class M_Page{

private static $instance;

private function __construct(){
     $mMysql = M_Mysql::getInstance();
}

public static function getInstance(){
    if (self::$instance==null)
        self::$instance = new M_Page;
    return self::$instance;
}

function all(){
    $result = $mMysql->Select('SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY date DESC');
    return $result;
}

class M_Mysql{
private static $instance;
private $link;

private function __construct(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.CP1251');  
    $this->link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER,
                    DB_PASS, DB_NAME) or die("Error:".mysqli_error($link));
}
public static function getInstance(){
    if (self::$instance == null)
        self::$instance = new M_Mysql();
    return self::$instance;
}

public function Select($sql){
    $result = mysqli_query($this->link, $sql);
    if(!$result) 
    die(mysqli_error($this->link));
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $rows = array();
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        $rows[]=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    }
    return $rows;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что `$mMysql` в конструкторе никак не связана с `$mMysql` в методе `all()` - это две разных локальных переменных.

```
private function __construct(){
     $mMysql = M_Mysql::getInstance();
}
```

Переменная здесь является локальной и не записывается в текущий объект. Соответственно, в методе `all()` идёт обращение тоже к локальной переменной, которой не существует и фактически идёт вызов `$result = null->Select('SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY date DESC');`

Чтобы избавиться от ошибки, вам нужно сделать свойство класса, в которое будет записываться объект подключения к БД и обращаться в коде уже к нему.

Comment: Или определить переменную глобальной

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что надо вынести создание объекта M_Mysql из конструктора и записать просто как свойство класса M_Page?

Comment: Нет, создавать его нужно в конструкторе, но записывать в $this->db, например. Ну и точно не стоит делать её глобальной - это плохая практика.